# Logic with date function

Tags: c, date, pointers

My goal is to add the number of days to a date and return the correct date.

I have the user input a date (dd,mm,yyyy) and also the number of days they wish to go into the future (days).

Could you help improve my logic

My resulted output is if I enter a date eg: 18/10/2014 and add 100 days I get the date 118/10/2014 which obviously isn't right.

```
void dateafter(int *pd, int *pm, int *py, int *pdtm, int *pdty, int *days ){

while(*days >= 0){

    if(*days > *pdty){
        *py += 1;
        daymonthyear(*pm, *py,  *pdtm, *pdty);
        *days -= *pdty;
    }
    if(*days > *pdtm - *pd){
        *pm = *pm + 1;

        if(*pm > 12){
            *pm = 1;
            *py = *py + 1;
        }

        daymonthyear(*pm,*py,*pdtm,*pdty);
        *days -= *pdtm;
    }
    else{
        *pd += *days;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

pdtm refers to days this month and pdty refers to pdty
daymonthyear calculates the number of days per month and year.

Thanks

Comment: If you know it's "obviously not right" then you also should know *why* it is not right.

Comment: Converted to the number of days from base date. To re-converted to date by adding the number of days.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date to unix time. see http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime will do this.

Number of seconds add to it. (one day = 24 * 60 * 60) seconds.

Convert back by using strftime

Answer (score 0):

There are some logical errors in your code, although they don't necessarily affect your example.

```
if(*days > *pdty){
    *py += 1;
    daymonthyear(*pm, *py,  *pdtm, *pdty);
    *days -= *pdty;
}
```

This piece of code works for all dates from March on. In January and February in a leap year, you skip this year's leap day, but your code skips next year's leap day. (You could skip the rest of the year, like you do with months, but you'd need to know the index of the day in the year.)

```
if(*days > *pdtm - *pd){
    *pm = *pm + 1;

    if(*pm > 12){
        *pm = 1;
        *py = *py + 1;
    }

    daymonthyear(*pm,*py,*pdtm,*pdty);
    *days -= *pdtm;
}
```

Here, you skip the rest of the month. After entering this block, `*pd` should be 1, but you just change the month. You also should subtract `*pdtm - *pd` from the days and you should do so before calculating next month's days.

Perhaps instead of one wrapper `while`, your `if`s should be `while`s:

```
while (days > restof(year)) ...    // do year advancement stuff
while (days > restof(month)) ...   // do month advancement stuff
// advance days that are left
```

In your example, the day 118 indicates that the days have just been added to the date's days, i.e. that you enter the `else` clause in the first pass. Which values of `pdtm` and `pdty` do you pass to the function? (Moreover, why do they have to be passed? Why not make them local?)